# Sails js - Creates a copy of assets

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

We are considering porting our project to Sails.js. Our static assets are quite large - more than 3 GB. So, this has created a serious limitation as it doubles the size of our app. Can we modify Sails js to prevent this default behavior or can some one recommend some other framework?

Comment: Are assets auto-loaded into the sails?

Comment: @Gelidus Just copied the static files of our app into assets folder, and it automatically created a .tmp/public folder where all the assets have been copied

Comment: Sails creates that folder as public server folder. I would try to go to configuration file and set "path": { public: } to assets folder

Comment: @Gelidus which config file

Comment: You can go to tasks/ directory and change grunt file that copy assets into .tmp/public to select only the most importans or create some virtual route that point directly to original assets directory (copy.js is the file, I don't remember very well)

Answer (score 8):

Sails uses Grunt to copy your assets into (by default) a clean **.tmp/public** folder every time the app is lifted.  This allows you to pick and choose which assets should be made public, and also lets you compile and minify assets in different environments.  This doesn't necessarily double the size of your app unless you're putting **.tmp** under version control, but if you have a lot of assets it can certainly make your app slow to start.

The simplest solution here is to turn off Grunt and serve your static assets directly from the **assets** folder.  To do that:

1. Delete the **Gruntfile.js** (or rename it to **Gruntfile.js.bak**)
2. Create a new config file called **config/assets.js** (or whatever you like; the name doesn't matter), and put the following inside:

   ```
   module.exports = {
     paths: {
       public: __dirname+"/../assets"
     } 
   };
   ```

The reason to put this in a new config file rather than **config/local.js** is that **local.js** is in your **.gitignore** file by default, so if you're using Git for version control you'd have to recreate that file every time you install the app on a new machine.

Like I said, this is the simplest solution, but it has some drawbacks:

- No more automatic compiling / minifying of assets in production mode
- No more automatic linking of Javascript / CSS files using the [asset pipeline](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Assets/TaskAutomation.html?q=asset-pipeline)

If you want to keep those features, but still avoid copying lots of files into **.tmp**, then the answer lies in modifying the default Grunt tasks (that's what they're in your project for!).

Answer (score 0):

In Sails.js 0.11 you may just add next code to .sailsrc file:

```
"hooks": {
 "grunt": false
}
```